# crystal reports and custom sorting 2

Tags: crystal-reports

Help please
I have a project at school to create crystal report 
where I have three columns [itemcode---price----Change]
Item codes has five different codes and all I need is how do I sort two of those items 
say cu-8967 and mp-7865 this applies for all CU and MP items and under changes calculate 
their differences.
Any guidance would great appreciated .
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We can't help you without seeing your relevant code.

Comment: Itemcodes shows, stad prices shows, but my problem is how do I go about sorting only those codes and performing the subtraction, is all done in the designer in crystal report release XI

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using crystal report formula.
write a formula like

```
totext({itemcode},"00",0)
```

and then drag and drop the formula where you want to show the result.